# Variable Syntax Order

Tags: python

Simple question here. When assigning a variable why does the order have to be:

```
variable = 5
#and not
5 = variable
```

Is it because we can't assign values to variables? Does it have something to do with how a computer stores variables to memory? Or is it arbitrary? Just starting to learn to code so forgive the novice question.

Comment: You cannot have variable starting with number in python. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/

Comment: Because you are setting the variable to equal 5, not 5 to equal to the variable. Because Python aims to read like human language, it is more natural to put it on the left.

Comment: They had to pick one direction or the other when they were designing things. They picked this one. It's like driving on the left or the right.

Comment: Voted to reopen, OPs question is about the directionality of assignment, not about the valid assignment target names

Answer (score 3):

It's arbitrary. Some languages have it the other way around, but they usually use a syntax like
`5 -> variable` or `5 → variable` — languages that use `=` or `:=` for assignment generally put the target of the assignment on the left.

Comment: Thanks so much. Didn't expect such fast feedback!